# Does defining the constraint PRIMARY KEY already makes sure that the column values are unique and not null or do you have to define it seperately?

Tags: sql

Does defining the constraint PRIMARY KEY already makes sure that the column values are unique and not null or do you have to define it seperately?

Comment: There is no need for separate constraints.

Comment: A primary key by definition must be unique.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But one exception is Sqlite.

See https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

> Each row in a table with a primary key must have a unique combination of values in its primary key columns. For the purposes of determining the uniqueness of primary key values, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs. If an INSERT or UPDATE statement attempts to modify the table content so that two or more rows have identical primary key values, that is a constraint violation.

> According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not the case in SQLite. Unless the column is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or the table is a WITHOUT ROWID table or the column is declared NOT NULL, SQLite allows NULL values in a PRIMARY KEY column. SQLite could be fixed to conform to the standard, but doing so might break legacy applications. Hence, it has been decided to merely document the fact that SQLite allows NULLs in most PRIMARY KEY columns.